# How to add a link in fcm-django notification?

Tags: python, django, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on a project where I am using fcm-django for sending push notifications to a devices. I want to include a link in the notification that opens a specific page in the web app when clicked. How can I add a link to the notification using fcm-django?

Here is my code

```py
from firebase_admin.messaging import Message
from firebase_admin.messaging import Notification
from fcm_django.models import FCMDevice

fcm_devices_of_this_user = FCMDevice.objects.filter(user=user_obj, active=True)
if fcm_devices_of_this_user:
   fcm_devices_of_this_user.send_message(
      MESSAGE(
        notification=NOTIFICATION(title=notification_for, body=message)
      )
   )
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer of above question...

```py
from firebase_admin.messaging import Message
from firebase_admin.messaging import Notification, WebpushConfig, WebpushFCMOptions
from fcm_django.models import FCMDevice

fcm_devices_of_this_user = FCMDevice.objects.filter(user=user_obj, active=True)
if fcm_devices_of_this_user:
   fcm_devices_of_this_user.send_message(
      MESSAGE(
        notification=NOTIFICATION(title=notification_for, body=message),
        webpush=WebpushConfig(fcm_options=WebpushFCMOptions(link="https://facebook.com"))
      )
   )
```